# scheduling 2 week vacation time to 70 employees

Tags: python, python-itertools

General idea:

1. Number are 1 to 6
2. Each Person chooses 5 number.
3. If number repeat after 3 times, select next available from the chosen one
4. First chosen number is the prefered and last one the least preferred

   - Jean chose 1,2,3,4,5
   - Claude chose 1,2,3,4,5
   - Van chose 1,2,3,4,5
   - Dam chose 1,2,3,4,5

I would like to have the final result giving those result :

- Jean = 1,2
- Claude = 1,2
- Van = 1,2
- Dam = 3,4

UPDATE 1:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ids_names = {
    ("01", "Jean"),
    ("02", "Claude"),
    ("03", "Van"),
    ("04", "Damme"),
    ("05", "Kristopher"),
    ("06", "Bianca"),
}

week_pool = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

employee_choices = OrderedDict([
    ("01", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("02", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("03", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("04", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("05", [2,3,4,5,6]),
    ("06", [1,2,3]),
])

assignments = [ ]

tracking = {week_num: 0 for week_num in week_pool}
for element in employee_choices.items():
    assignments.append(week_pool)
    print('assignments: {}'.format(assignments))
    for week_num in employee_choices:
        if tracking[week_pool] < 3:
            assignments[-1].append(week_pool)
            tracking[week_num] += 1
            if len(assignments[-1]) == 2:
                break
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 30, in 
if tracking[week_pool] < 3:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

UPDATE THAT WORK !

```
weeks = list(range(1, 52))
tracking = {week_num: 0 for week_num in weeks}
assignments = [ ]
for preferences in [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]:
    assignments.append([ ])
    print('assignments: {}'.format(assignments))
    for week_num in preferences:
        if tracking[week_num] < 3:
            assignments[-1].append(week_num)
            tracking[week_num] += 1
            if len(assignments[-1]) == 2:
                break
```

Comment: Can you explain rule 3 better and the expected results?

Comment: Does each person select the numbers in order or randomly?

Comment: Hi pylang! so as you can see on the "result" you can see person 1,2, and 3 all got number 1 and 2 assigned, even if person 4 chose the exact same number, person 4 got 3,4, since 3 people before him chose 1 and 2 as their preferred numbers

Each person select the number they want, could be 20,12,31,8,50

Comment: I want a formula that would assign the vacancy of 70 people, giving them 5 week choice, then, by seniority, it would assign them automatically the vacancy they chose, respecting the fact only 3 people can be on vacancy the same week. and two week of vacancy allowed per employee

Comment: So the real scale would be 70 person, can choose 5 number of their choice (52 weeks a years) so 1 to 52, they each get two week assigned to them depending if anyone who have more seniority have chosen the same (3 people can be on vacancy the same week)

Comment: This is quite  a complex problem.  I assume the preferences each person selects is ranks from most preferred to least preferred week correct (so the requested weeks may be holidays, i.e. [1, 52, 13, 31, 27]?

Comment: Hi pyang, thank for your quick answer, and yes, exactly, holiday dont cause an issue,

Comment: Someone from python forum said this >

"You have a list of lists ([p1, p2, p3, ...]). Loop through that. Then loop through the sublist (sorted), picking the top two values that haven't been picked three times already. You don't need itertools, you just need a couple loops and a way to keep track of the values you've already chosen (a dictionary would work well, or a list since they are all integers)."

.... sound quite complicate ...

Comment: This is true.  I would start by making a pool of availabe weeks.  Then I would recommend an `OrderedDict` of (employee ids, list of requests) pairs, ranked by seniority.  Try iterating each employees and their requests to see if each request is possible from a pool of available weeks.  You will find likely received more input by 1) clarifying your question with an example of expected results and 2) trying some code.  With those in place I can assist further.

Comment: Great ! Thank i will work on this and keep you updated !

Comment: So i just did a little update, am i doing the right thing or is this completely wrong ?

Comment: I think you mean `tracking[week_num]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Revisions**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Translate employe ids
ids_names = {
    ("01", "Jean"),
    ("02", "Claude"),
    ("03", "Van"),
    ("04", "Damme"),
    ("05", "Kristopher"),
    ("06", "Bianca"),
}

week_pool = list(range(1, 53))
employee_choices = OrderedDict([
    ("01", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("02", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("03", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("04", [1,2,3,4,5]),
    ("05", [2,3,4,5,6]),
    ("06", [1,2,3]),
])
```

**Description**

08-31: You are off to a good start.  I'll update with notes here and give you hints.  A few minor notes:

1. If two people have the same name, programmatically it gets confusing.  You are better off assigning numbers to employees since these are unique.  So not to confuse ids numbers with weeks, let's uses numeric strings.  If we name to find a name, we can later search the translation dictionary.
2. `range()` is a shorter way to get span of integers, but your approach also works.
3. The `OrderedDict` is a good call.  You can use this to order seniority.  You just have to make sure your weeks are in a separate container, e.g. a list. I added some extra names for a later point.
4. On style, we use lowercase for variable names.  Also we keep lines short (79 characters) so use returns.

**Goals**

1. Structure the input data (**OK**)
2. Make a scheduling function that:

   - processes the employees and the available weeks
   - ...

Comment: Wow pylang, that is great, take a look to the UPDATED version, for some reason it give me this : 

C:\Users\h.villeneuve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/h.villeneuve/PycharmProjects/OrderedDict/OrderedDict.py
assignments: [[]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/h.villeneuve/PycharmProjects/OrderedDict/OrderedDict.py", line 33, in <module>
    if tracking[week_num] < 3:
KeyError: '01'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Pylang, i would REALLY love to be able using the OrderedDict, i tried really hard but i receive to many errors, i think its simpler to compare list with list, atleast with my limited knowledge

Comment: Nice effort.  First, update the post with all your code including `OrderedDict` and what didn't work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on including important information.  Second and most importantly, update your question by stating exactly what you want to do (scheduling 2 week vacation time to 70 employees), explain that the numbers are requested/preferred work weeks from employees and explain your constraint of seniority clearly.  Kudos on brevity, but a well formed question will help everyone including yourself, and prevent it from being closed.

Comment: Iterate a dictionary as (key, value) pairs like this `for employee, choices in employee_choices.items():`.  `choices` is now the preferred weeks.